# Why is there junk data in the first node of my linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

It appears that there is junk data in the first node of my list. Why would this be?

These are the definitions of the structs i'm using.

```
typedef struct node { 
   char *x; 
   struct node *next; 
}node;

typedef struct { 
   struct node *head;
}list;
```

// create_list() function :

```
list* create_list(){
    list *myList = malloc(sizeof(myList));
    myList->head = NULL;
    if (myList->head != NULL){ 
       return NULL; 
    }
    return myList; 
 }
```

Here is the implementation of the add_to_list function

```
int add_to_list(list* ll, char* item){

    node *current = ll->head;
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (!new_node){
        fprintf(stderr, "error allocating mem.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(new_node->x, item);
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if(ll->head == NULL){
       ll->head = new_node;
       return 0;
    }else{
       while(current->next){
       current = current->next;
    }
     current->next = new_node;
   }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the print_list(); funcntion

```
void print_list(list *ll){

    node *current = ll->head;
    while(current){
       printf("%s\t\n",current->x);
       current = current->next;
    }
}
```

when I call the function in main.c here is how i'm doing it :

```
list *newList = create_list();

char test_var = 'k';

add_to_list(newList, &test_var);

printf("printing whole list : \n");

print_list(newList);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. More urgently, we're going to bed to see the calling code in an MCVE ([MCVE]), please.  We can't tell from this code what's going wrong.

Comment: You don't show whether the `x` element in your node structure is an array or a pointer.  If it's an array, could you be overflowing it?  If it's a pointer, you don't allocate any space before you copy.

Comment: I updated my question for more clarity. May you please look again?

Comment: You create the list with the `create_list()` function but you've not shown it. Please read the description of an MCVE again.  The C is for complete or compilable.

Comment: It rather depends on what the black box `create_list()` function does. You should include `print_list` too just in case your list is fine but your printing code is not.

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/nypIua)

Comment: in function: create_list(), this code: `list *myList = malloc(sizeof(myList));
    myList->head = NULL;
    if (myList->head != NULL){ 
       return NULL; 
    }` is nonsense.  What needs to be checked for NULL is not the contents of `.head` but rather the returned value from the call to `malloc()`

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are passing a char as a char pointer (ie a string). 
Change

```
char test_var = 'k';
```

to

```
char *test_var = "k";
```

and change the call to

```
add_to_list(newList, &test_var)
```

to

```
add_to_list(newList, test_var)
```

Comment: Good answer. It'd be nice to explain exactly why this is happening though. The reason it happens is because `strcpy(new_node->x, item);` is called with the single character, which probably won't have a null character after it. Thus, it'll read the letter, then keep reading *random memory* until it finds a 0.

Comment: There's more to this than just this answer. That `strcpy`, even with this change, is completely wrong. no memory is allocated for the `x` pointer to point to prior to the `strcpy` invoke. The OPs code, even with this change is invoking *undefined* behavior.

Answer (score 0):

regarding this statement:

```
strcpy(new_node->x, item);
```

the 'x' field is a uninitialized pointer. so using that pointer to point to the destination area is undefined behavior.

Writing to where a uninitialized pointer points could result in a seg fault event.

AND is the reason for the corrupted data.  Your just lucky a seg fault didn't occur nor any of the other data being corrupted.

if you know the max length of the data, then you could change the struct definition so the field 'x' is an array of char rather than a pointer.

Otherwise, suggest using something similar to:

```
new_node->x = strdup( data );
if( !new_node->x )
{ // then strdup() failed
    perror( "strdup failed" );
    // call a cleanup function here
    free( new_node );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, strdup successful
```